# for which values of x $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(\ln x)^{\ln n} }$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to know for which values of $x$ this series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(\ln x)^{\ln n} }$$ converges.

This series is defined for:

$(\ln x)^{\ln n} \ne 0 \Rightarrow \ln x \ne 0\Rightarrow x \ne 1$ .

and for $x>0$

So the series is defined for $ \forall x \in (0,1) \cup (1, + \infty)$.

$a_n=\frac{1}{(\ln x)^{\ln n} } \sim 0 \Leftrightarrow (\ln x)^{\ln n}  \sim  \infty  \Leftrightarrow  |\ln x|>1 \Leftrightarrow  x>e \lor x<e^{-1}$.

Applying the comparison criterion we have:

$\frac{1}{(\ln x)^{\ln n} }< \frac{1}{x^{\ln n} }<\frac{1}{x^n }=(\frac{1}{x })^n$

and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{x })^n$ diverges for $\frac{1}{x } \ge 1 \Leftrightarrow x \le 1$

So the given series diverges for $0<x<\frac{1}{e}$

Now I don't know how to prove that the series converges or diverges for $x>e$, seen that the root and ratio tests are inconclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

- First, you need $\ln x>0$ (i.e., $x>1$) for things to be defined, as otherwise you have a quantity of the form $c^t$ with $c=\ln x \leq 0$ and $t=\ln n \notin \mathbb{N}$. But how do you define $(-1/2)^{0.3}$, for instance?
- then, for $x>1$
  $$
  (\ln x)^{\ln n} = e^{\ln n\cdot \ln\ln x} = n^{\ln\ln x}
  $$
  Now, do you recognize a $p$-series?

Comment: I can try: this series converges $ \Leftrightarrow - \ln ( \ln x)>1  \Leftrightarrow   \ln ( \ln x)< -1 \Leftrightarrow    \ln x < e^{-1}  \Leftrightarrow  x<e^{e^{-1} }  $

Comment: Not quite: you need $\ln\ln x > 1$  (no minus sign). The series itself is $$\sum_n \frac{1}{(\ln x)^{\ln n}}=\sum_n \frac{1}{n^{\ln \ln x}}$$ @Anne

Comment: ok so the final result is $x>e^e$ thanks

Comment: You're welcome! @Anne

Comment: To the downvoter: is there somethings wrong with my answer? If so, what, and how can I improve it?

Answer (score 1):

The integral test applies nicely here.  Proceeding we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_1^L \frac1{(\log(x))^{\log(t)}}\,dt&\overbrace{=}^{t= e^u}\int_0^{\log(L)} \frac{e^u}{(\log(x))^{u}}\,du\\\\
&=\int_0^{\log(L)}\left(\frac{e}{\log(x)}\right)^u\,du\tag1
\end{align}$$

The limit as $L\to \infty$ of the integral in $(1)$ converges when $\log(x)>e$, or values of $x>e^e$ and diverges otherwise.  Hence the series of interest converges when $x>e^e$ and diverges otherwise.